# Website on CDN - server switching based on country/geography

Tags: cdn

Im going to implement CDN, but im still confuse how the CDN recognize where the request come from. for example, I have 2 servers. one in US and one in Japan. when request come from Hong Kong, I want the contents served from Japan server, because it closer. So, how the CDN can recognize the request from Hong Kong and serve contents from Japan?

If in cluster, we have load-balancer to distribute workload, how about CDN to serving contents from specific server depending on request location?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Obligatory Vixie ACM paper link: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1647302

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "BGP tomfoolery".  The medium-length answer is, in addition to BGP tomfoolery, DNS tomfoolery.  The longer answer is... well, quite a bit longer, and you're not paying me to explain geobalancing, which ain't an easy topic to begin with.  Perhaps someone will be along shortly to help.  If not, [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072190469) is one of the better ones I've found, and will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use akamai and leave it to them on how it works, basically you should be checking you static file speed after using CDN . For example if we wish to ride a bike it is not necessary to know how the bike works !!

Comment: If you don't want to build your own I would also recommend akamai

Comment: For what sounds like a smaller shop, Akamai is massively expensive and overkill. A contract-free pay-as-you-go CDN would be a better option (there are a lot of them these days). See http://cloudharmony.com/clouds_cdn for a starter list.